# Having serious issues with functions, dates, CASE and IIF statements in SQL

Tags: sql-server, case

I have been working on these queries and then some, but I cannot seem to get these three quite right. I am honestly not trying to get people to do my work for me, but any help/tips would be extremely appreciated.

This query is supposed to return 4 columns: VendorName, InvoiceTotal,
 InvoiceDate and InvoiceAge (use the appropriate function that will
 return the number of days between the InvoiceDate and 12/1/2008).
 Filter the results to only return rows where there is a balance due
 and the InvoiceAge is greater than 132. Sort the results by
 VendorName. No errors, but it is not quite right.

```
 SELECT VendorName, InvoiceTotal, InvoiceDate,
DATEDIFF(day, InvoiceDate, '12/1/2008') AS InvoiceAge
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 0 
AND InvoiceDate > 132
ORDER BY VendorName;-- Not showing invoices over 132
```

This query is the one that has been giving me the most trouble; it should  return 4 columns: VendorName, InvoiceNumber,
InvoiceTotal, and PotentialDiscount.
PotentialDiscount is a column that will contain the result expression from a
CASE statement that contains 4 conditionals based on the InvoiceTotal column:

```
    SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, PotentialDiscount =
CASE InvoiceTotal
WHEN InvoiceTotal < 100 THEN 'No discount consideration'
WHEN InvoiceTotal 101-500 THEN 'Discount potential 3'
WHEN InvoiceTotal > 501-1000 THEN 'Discount potential 2'
WHEN InvoiceTotal > 1000 THEN 'Discount potential 1'
END AS PotentialDiscount
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal;
```

However, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '<'.

And lastly, this one should return 3 columns: VendorName, BalanceDue: balance due calculated column using the SUM function, DebtLevel: nested IIF functions, then filter the results to only include vendors where a balance is due and sort the results from the sum of largest balance to smallest.

```
    SELECT VendorName, SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) AS BalanceDue,
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal) > 11000, 'Very high', 
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal) BETWEEN 11000 AND 500, 'High',
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal) BETWEEN 500 AND 200, 'Medium',
IIF(SUM(InvoiceTotal) <= 500, 'Low') AS DebtLevel
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.InvoiceID
WHERE InvoiceTotal > 0
ORDER BY VendorName DESC;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Even the slightest assistance would be extremely helpful.... Thank you.

Comment: This smells like homework do I'm not giving a full answer but, 1) check what you are filtering on in your where clause, 2) look at the syntax for the case statement, 3) put all your `IIF` statements on the same line and you should see your problem.

Comment: 2nd query : your CASE syntax is wrong. should be CASE WHEN ..... remove the InvoiceTotal after the CASE

Comment: @Squirrel: Thanks, still error at the "END, PotentialDiscount'


`SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, PotentialDiscount =
CASE WHEN InvoiceTotal < 100 THEN 'No discount consideration'
WHEN InvoiceTotal = 101-500 THEN 'Discount potential 3'
WHEN InvoiceTotal > 501-1000 THEN 'Discount potential 2'
WHEN InvoiceTotal > 1000 THEN 'Discount potential 1'
END, PotentialDiscount
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal;`

Comment: Is InvoiceDate a datetime or an integer?

Comment: `InvoiceDate > 132` in your WHERE condition in the first query is going to select all dates > 1901-05-13.

Comment: Also your IIF statements have a lot of unclosed brackets. And the updated thing you put in comments should have `, PotentialDiscount` removed from the select

Comment: @ZLK: Thank you SO MUCH for the help. However, I am still having issues with the IIF statements. I tried to close all of them, but it is causing more errors. I tried Googling nested IIF statements hours ago, but with little help.  Even the slightest tip would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1**

Seemingly you are comparing `InvoiceDate` to 132, whereas what you need is `InvoiceAge`. Noting that you can't use a newly created alias directly in `WHERE` predicate of the same query, you would either need to repeat the whole `DATEDIFF` expression in the where clause:

```
AND DATEDIFF(day, '2008-01-12', InvoiceDate) > 132
```

You could also save the repetition by wrapping a derived table or CTE, e.g.

```
WITH InvoiceCte AS
(
   SELECT VendorName, InvoiceTotal, InvoiceDate,
          DATEDIFF(day, '2008-01-12', InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceAge,
          InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal AS InvoiceNett
   FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
        ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
)
SELECT * FROM InvoiceCte
WHERE InvoiceNett > 0 
      AND InvoiceAge > 132
ORDER BY VendorName;
```

Also noting that [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms189794.aspx) is `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`, and would also advise to use ISO 8601 style date formatting to prevent confusion on local date formats).

**Query 2**

As others have mentioned, you can't use `CASE x WHEN y THEN z` syntax for ranges of data. You'll need to use the `CASE WHEN condition THEN` format instead. Also, noting that CASEs will match only on the first, you can eliminate the gaps in your ranges by simplifying this to:

```
SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal,
  CASE
    WHEN InvoiceTotal < 100 THEN 'No discount consideration'
    WHEN InvoiceTotal < 500 THEN 'Discount potential 3'
    WHEN InvoiceTotal < 1000 THEN 'Discount potential 2'
    ELSE 'Discount potential 1'
  END AS PotentialDiscount
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
  ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal;
```

**Query 3**

Like the first query, you'll be able to prevent the repeated `SUM(InvoiceTotal)` with a CTE or Derived table, and like the second query, the nested `IIF's` will also only need to check for the lower bound, since the upper bound will have been handled by the previous nesting.

You'll also want to fix the join condition to ON `Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorId`. I'm assuming 'Low' is the fallback classification, otherwise you'll to provide an additional value for the last `IIF` if the `Low` criterion isn't met:

```
WITH MyCte AS
(
    SELECT 
        VendorName, SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) AS BalanceDue,
        SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS SumInvoiceTotal
    FROM Vendors 
      JOIN Invoices
      ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorId
    WHERE InvoiceTotal > 0
    GROUP BY VendorName
)
SELECT VendorName, BalanceDue, SumInvoiceTotal,
    IIF(SumInvoiceTotal > 11000, 'Very high', 
        IIF(SumInvoiceTotal > 500, 'High',
            IIF(SumInvoiceTotal > 200, 'Medium',
                'Low'))) AS DebtLevel
FROM MyCte
    ORDER BY VendorName DESC;
```